# How to reduce the functions in my Script for an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

*grammar

I have managed to achieve the function I need to but it is more manual than I would like - I have to run several different functions to achieve a complete array of results rather than one function which would produce the full array. Additionally - if I wanted to make this a generic script would I just use getID("ENTER ID") rather than getActive()?

Could anyone help in trimming down my script below (it continues for about 20 sheets)?

```
function CopyDispatchWithHeaders (){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var source = ss.getSheets()[1];
    var range = source.getRange("B3:AB400");

    range.copyValuesToRange(0, 1, 27, 1, 500);
}

function CopyDispatchReport1() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[2];
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[0];

    sheet1.getRange("B4:AB500").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,500,27), {contentsOnly:true});
```

}

```
function CopyDispatchReport2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[0];

  sheet1.getRange("B4:AB500").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,500,27), {contentsOnly:true});
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all your `CopyDispatchReport1()`, `CopyDispatchReport2()` and etc... functions with this:

```
var 
  map = [{sheet1: 2, sheet2: 0},{sheet1: 3, sheet2: 0}],
  i,
  runner;

for (i in map) {

  (function(obj) {

    var
      ss,
      sheet1,
      sheet2;

    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[obj.sheet1];
    sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[obj.sheet1];

    sheet1.getRange("B4:AB500").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,500,27), {contentsOnly:true});

  })(map[i]);
}
```

First you need to create a map (array of objects in our case), which will store necessary IDs for your sheets. The next you can iterate that map and call anonymous function which will receive an object with `sheet1` and `sheet2` properties.

You can add any parameter to this map. For example: `B4:AB500`

Lets modify our map:

```
map = [{sheet1: 2, sheet2: 0, range: 'B4:AB500'},{sheet1: 3, sheet2: 0, range: 'B6:AB500'}]

sheet1.getRange(obj.range).copyTo...
```

Comment: Hi Ali, sorry but I'm still a little unclear about creating the array. I understand that I need to create a for loop but I'm unsure on how to do that? Could you please help?